# Are the wiktionary definitions for 切 qiè correct?

Tags: translation, dictionary

Definitions 2 through 11 for pronunciation [qiè](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%88%87#Chinese) are missing in the 11 dicitionaries I compare from qtranslate. Would they be recognizable in mainland chinese?

- to be close to
- to bite tightly;
- to clench
- to correspond to;
- to match
  (traditional Chinese medicine) to feel the pulse
- eager;
- ardent
- urgent;
- pressing
- all;
- entire
- must;
- by all means
- main point
- (phonetics) Short for 反切 (fǎnqiè, “fanqie”).
- (chiefly women's speech, colloquial) An interjection conveying a slight sense of disdain or dissatisfaction.

Comment: Some of those probably only make sense when it is used _as part of a word_. E.g., `一切` means "all", but `切` does not generally mean that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From CantoDict Dictionary:

> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/793/
>
> (jyutping) cit3, (pinyin) qie1
>
> [1] cut; slice; chop; mince; carve
>
> [2] (indicates that the previous two characters are 反切 notation)
>
> [3] [math] tangent
>
> (jyutping) cit3, (pinyin) qie4
>
> [1] correspond to; conform to; accord with
>
> [2] close to; near to
>
> [3] eager; anxious; keen
>
> [4] be sure to; must
>
> (jyutping) cai3, (pinyin) qie4
>
> [1a ]all; whole

~

From the question:

> **to be close to**

*(Match pinyin /qie4/ [2]) close to*

> **to bite tightly**

*only work in idiom 咬牙切齒, which literally means 'bite and cut with teeth, therefore, 切 itself doesn't contain the meaning of 'bite'  only contains the meaning of 'cut' here*

> **to clench**

*切 doesn't have the meaning of to 'clench' . The editor might have confused  by the expression '切齒',  which literally means 'cut with teeth'  and this action results in you shut your jaws tight, thus extend to the meaning of 'clenching jaws'*

> **to correspond to**

*(Match pinyin /qie4/ [1] correspond to)*

> **to match (traditional Chinese medicine) to feel the pulse**

*to feel the pulse is 搭脈; 切脈 means 'hack the blood vein' which is a martial art term, the editor made a mistake again*

> **eager**

*(Match pinyin /qie4/ [3] eager)*

> **ardent**

*(Match pinyin /qie4/ [3] keen)*

> **urgent**

*only work in compound word '急切' which means ' urgently close'. '切' in '急切' doesn't mean urgent, it means 'close' or 'near'; only '急' in '急切' means urgent*

> **pressing**

*only work in compound word '逼切' which means 'pressingly close'. '切' in '逼切' doesn't mean 'pressing', it means 'close' or 'near'; only '逼' in '逼切' means 'pressing'*

> **all**

*(Match pinyin /qie4/ [1a])but it only work in compound word '一切', '切' itself doesn't mean 'all' - Even the CantoDict dictionary made the same mistake*

> **entire**

*(Match pinyin /qie4/ [1a])- 'all' extended to mean 'entire'*

> **must**

*(Match pinyin /qie4/ [4] must)*

> **by all means**

*the editor was confused by the expression '不顧一切' which literally means '不顧'(not care), 一切 (all); Only the idiom '不顧一切' means 'by all means', '切' doesn't*

> **main point**

*'main point' in Chinese is '要點', the editor might have confused by a common phrase '切中要點' which literally means '切中'(cut correctly into) 要點(the main point).*

> **(phonetics) Short for 反切 (fǎnqiè, “fanqie”).**

*(Match (pinyin) qie1 [2])*

> **(chiefly women's speech, colloquial) An interjection conveying a slight sense of disdain or dissatisfaction.**

*'**啐**' sounded like '切'. It is a phonetic loan word for an exclamation that express disdain or dissatisfaction*

Comment: Not to be nit picky but can you edit your answer so your comments are not block-quoted, it’s hard to tell where your notes begin and end.

Comment: @user3306356 I used bold font for the Wiki entry.  Better now?

Comment: if you could un-quote your own comments that would be best. I did one edit on your answer as an example.